# Writing an algorithm using the graph theory for this

Tags: algorithm, probability, graph-algorithm

I don't know whether here is a good place to ask this or not. So I'm sorry if I am in a wrong forum.

How can I solve below question in an algorithmic way ?

There are n boxes in a room. All of them has an orange within except one. Mr.X wants to **find the empty box without opening it** (i.e if he opens the empty box, he will lose the game !). There could be some informations about other boxes within each box which if Mr.X reads the informations can find out if the other box is empty or not. We (as an informed third-party person) write a table about boxes and informations within and give it to Mr.X. The table is a matrix, if M(i, j) = 'Y' it means that there is some information about box j in box i which you can find out if it's empty or not by opening box i, if M(i, j) = 'N' it means there is not information about box j in box i.
Imagine Mr.X opens the boxes optimally using the table (i.e he opens boxes as few as possible). Now calculate the probability of finding the empty box without opening it.
Note: All boxes have the same probability of being empty or not empty.

Example 1:

```
YYYYY
NYNNN
NNYNN
NNNYN
NNNNY
```

Probability : 0.8

Example 2:

```
YYNNY
NYNNY
NNYYY
NNNYY
NNNNY
```

Probability : 0.6

Hope someone can help me.
thanks a lot.

UPDATE:
Doing optimally means opening as few as possible the boxes **he doesn't know about** (i.e. if you know about it you can simply open it.).

Comment: Does MrX have to choose beforehand which boxes he'll open? Otherwise minimizing the number of boxes opened isn't optimal. Consider: YYNNN, NYYNN, NNYYN, NNNYY, NNNNY.  The minimal number of boxes to open is 2 (the first and third) -- and gives a probability of 0.6 of finding the missing orange. But opening boxes 1, then 2, then 3 gives a probability of 0.8 -- because if he opens boxes 2 and 3 he already knows they'll contain oranges.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks for your reply. This is exactly one of my questions that I can't figure out even from the main question (I wrote the translated one), But I think the second answer is the true one because my algorithm is already solving it with 0.6 and when I submit the program (it's an ACM-like question) it always solves only 40 percent of questions. thanks a lot.

Comment: @PaulHankin How did you calculate the probability ? What about the 5th box if you only open first to 3rd ?

Comment: NOTE: At main question : "Doing optimally means opening as few as possible the boxes **he doesn't know about**". So I think if he know about the box it's OK to open it.

Comment: @MohammadAmin: You should update your original question to contain (and emphasise!) the important detail you mention in your last comment!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated that.

Comment: @MohammadAmin in my example, if you open the first 3 boxes you have complete explicit knowledge about the first 4 boxes. This, plus the the fact that there's exactly one missing orange lets you implicitly deduce the contents of the 5th box.

Comment: @PaulHankin Oh that's right. I didn't notice that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a directed graph such that each box is a vertex and if box i contains information on box j and i!=j then there's an edge from i to j.

You are now looking for the minimum number of vertices from which all other vertices are reachable, the solution to this problem can be found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/find-the-minimum-number-of-vertices-in-a-directed-graph-from-which-the-other-ver).

In order to find the empty box you must open as many boxes as the minimum number of vertices found above, hence the probability is 1-(minimum number of vertices)/(#boxes)

Note that in case there's a box pointing only to itself, we don't have to open it, as we can first open all other boxes and if the empty box wasn't found we know it's the last one, in case there's such a box then the probability is actually higher in 1/#boxes.

Thanks for your help [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Look at example 2, which edges should I remove ?

Comment: In this case there are no circles in the graph (directed) so there's no need to remove any edges. There are two vertices with in-degree 0 which are 1 and 3, so the probability is 0.6.

Comment: Oh your right. I'm sorry! But how can I write such an algorithm ? Should I find and choose an in-deg 0 vertex and use DFS to find corresponding vertices and do this again until I mark all of my vertices ?

Comment: You should look for an implementation of an algorithm for finding connected components in a directed graph

Comment: A->B, B->C, B->D, C->A, D->A is a graph where every cycle has an incoming edge, and no 0 in-degree vertices. It corresponds to YYNN, NYYY, YNYN, YNNY. I don't see how your method works in that case.

Comment: There's also a minor edge-case: you can ignore a single box -- since if you know the contents of N-1 boxes, you know the contents of all the boxes. This sometimes yields a smaller solution: YN, NY requires only 1 box to be opened, not two. Or indeed, if there's a single box, you don't need to open it know there's no orange in it, since it's given that exactly one box contains no orange.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/find-the-minimum-number-of-vertices-in-a-directed-graph-from-which-the-other-ver is the correct version of your algorithm I think (except for the edge-case mentioned above). Instead of removing an edge of a cycle, you can contract the cycle into a single vertex.